# How to use ODK in windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, odk

How to use ODK in windows Phone 8

or it having another Alternatives for doing this

please help me what's the problem with this

Answer (score 2):

OpenDataKit is not available on Windows Phone 8. It looks like it's not available on any mobile platforms at the moment

http://opendatakit.org/downloads/